# Track ViewState in CompositeDataBoundControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I created a `CustomDataBoundControl`. I implemented `CreateChildControls()`, but I am not actively doing anything to support viewstate and thus, I loose the data after a postback. I was looking in to this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479016.aspx

My problem is that the way the sample works with ViewState is using a `Pair` object, which holds key-value pairs and recreates a known data type in the collection of itemsIStateManager` implementation.

My control is more generic. I do not know the type of the objects coming in to the `datasource` property and I create the child controls via reflection in to the `datasource` objects. I create a `Table` control and fill it with `TableRow` controls, which I fill with `TableCell` controls.

I can't seem to bridge this gap between Dino`s example and my real-world implementation.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to data source controls, you don't use ViewState to retain the data.  As long as your building a control tree, the .NET framework will reload the viewstate of the controls in the control state.  You just need to store the viewstate for the core properties of the control, plus the number of items rendered.  This way, you can rerender the same control tree.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines, but how does the control render logic differ for data binding vs. a postback?

Comment: For data binding, you know the data you are displaying to the user.  On postback, you have to recreate the same control tree to match identically the previous control tree created.  You don't need to match the data, because again, ViewState will reload state for each control in the tree (as long as it's recreated at the right time, during init).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am recreating the control tree on `CreateChildControls()` and this gets called by the page's `OnLoad`' no? And what do I do if I want to do sorting during the postback?

Answer (score 0):

create the control tree  on init to maintain the ViewState, you need not populate the data in your controls but just create the controls. As per the page flow ViewState is enabled for the controls which are created in OnInit. Hope this helps.